# Referencing a parameterized type from an annotation

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I am trying to figure out how to reference a parameterized interface as an annotation attribute:

```
public class Example {
    public interface MyService<T extends Number> {
        T someNumber();
    }

    public class BaseServiceImpl<T extends Number> implements MyService<T> {
        @Override
        public T someNumber() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public @interface ServiceType {
        Class<? extends MyService<?>> value();
    }

    @ServiceType(BaseServiceImpl.class)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The above code fails with a type mismatch on the `@ServiceType` annotation. I believe the problem is with the bounds I have specified for the `value` attribute. I also noticed that when a type is not generic it works fine; e.g. `@ServiceType(IntegerService.class)` works given:

```
    public class IntegerService extends BaseServiceImpl<Integer> { /* ... */ }
```

What am I missing to get the rid of the mismatch error when trying to supply the generic type?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that class literals refer to raw class types. That is `BaseServiceImpl.class` is of type `Class<BaseServiceImpl>`, not `Class<BaseServiceImpl<? extends Number>>`. Change the return type of value to `Class<? extends MyService>` and it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

I think the annotated interface should bounded as follows:

```
public @interface ServiceType {
        Class<? extends MyService<? extends Number>> value();
}
```